# Getting Ready for 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, virtual

I'm starting to look at Magento 2.4, and the first thing I ran across is that it doesn't look like I can use a shared server. The hosting company has a VPS plan, which looks like it would work, but I wanted to confirm that on here before I move ahead.

1. Will a VPS be sufficient for implementing JDK, which is required for ElasticSearch
2. Are there any caveats about moving from a shared server to a VPS that aren't in the marketing literature?

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure if you would migrate from a lower M2 version or you come from M1 all the way

Moving to an vps normally means you have to manage the services too (mysql, apache, nginx, elasticsearch, etc)

To avoid using elasticsearch you can also use the module provided by Swissup to use Mysql as the search engine: https://github.com/swissup/module-search-mysql-legacy

Comment: Thanks. The VP does sound like a lot of work. We're a small company, and I'd rather use the time on marketing and sales. I would be coming from 2.3.6; this sounds ideal. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, my pleasure, I have customers in your case and normally place them in specialized hosting for magento like nexcess, magemojo, sonassi, that way I dont have to worry about hosting/system and can take advantage of the latest M2 updates/improvements (elasticsearch is supposed to increase performance not only in the search area but in the catalog navigation too as it's used to serve the products)